# Is it suggested to logout a user if they click back button and then forward button on the landing page after signing in but not logging out?

Tags: logout, back-button

For a non-banking enterprise web app, is it recommended to allow the user to log into the app on pressing back button and then forward button on a browser, when the user has logged in and is on the landing page but has not logged out.

Comment: Sure, seems reasonable.

Comment: @Ryan Do you mean it is ok to log them back in without having to enter credentials?

Comment: There's no "back in", is there? They already logged in.